# NLS_LANG cause problem with MATCH RECOGNIZE ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing to you because I identified an extremely weird problem while using MATCH_RECOGNIZE function in Oracle. The issue is that when I am not changing NLS_LANGUAGE to American the results are following.

```
+------------+------------+------+---------+--+
| VALID_FROM | VALID_TO   | CST  | ACTION  |  |
+------------+------------+------+---------+--+
| 27-01-2014 | 28-05-2014 | 2511 | Konkurs |  |
| 08-08-2014 | 06-10-2014 | 2511 | Konkurs |  |
|            |            | 2511 | Konkurs |  |
+------------+------------+------+---------+--+
```

However, when changed the results are correct and the extra record (3rd) is gone.

```
+------------+------------+------+---------+--+
| VALID_FROM | VALID_TO   | CST  | ACTION  |  |
+------------+------------+------+---------+--+
| 27-01-2014 | 28-05-2014 | 2511 | Konkurs |  |
| 08-08-2014 | 06-10-2014 | 2511 | Konkurs |  |
+------------+------------+------+---------+--+
```

Does any of you know why is this happening? The extra record is created out of the blue and I am unable to identify where does it come from. Please find below the part of match_recognize code.

```
match_recognize ( 
        PARTITION BY kundenr, oikhaendelse,DEFAULT_TK
        ORDER BY valid_to, valid_from
        MEASURES min (valid_from) valid_from, MAX (valid_to) valid_to
        PATTERN (a b *)
        DEFINE b AS valid_from <= prev (valid_to) 
  )
```

Comment: What is the data type of column `valid_to` and `valid_from`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It's a date.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: a DDL statement for your table; `INSERT` statements for some sample data that replicates the problem; `ALTER SESSION` statements to specify your NLS settings in both cases you are testing; and a complete query so that we can run it and replicate your problem. Please help us to help you by giving us all the information needed to replicate the issue. Also, you should not assume that everyone helping you is going to be one of the "Lads".

Comment: Unable to replicate this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=10dad26afddf7077fcf8f2edcb326362). This really needs a [MRE] from the OP to be able to see the issue as it might be related to the table structure or to the data or to the NLS settings.